# Android NFC Startup screen

Tags: android, broadcast, nfc

I am trying to read an NFC tag, when I click a button on my app. Currently I am able to detect the tag in default mode (Tag app installed in Nexus phone). but I am not able to get to display the activity chooser through which I want to launch my tag

```
public class NFC_button extends Activity
{

protected IntentFilter ifilter ;
private NfcAdapter adapter;

private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() 
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {

        if(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction()))
        {
            Parcelable[] messages = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
            NdefMessage[] ndefmessages;
            if(messages != null)
            {
                ndefmessages = new NdefMessage[messages.length];

                for(int i = 0;i<messages.length;i++)
                {
                    ndefmessages[i] = (NdefMessage)messages[i];
                }



            }

        }

    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    adapter=NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);


    ifilter = new IntentFilter();
    ifilter.addAction("android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED");
    ifilter.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");

}



@Override
protected void onResume() {
    registerReceiver(receiver, ifilter);

super.onResume();
}




}

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.nfc.example"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true"/>

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10"/>

<application

    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".NFC_ExampleActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".NFC_button">

      </activity>

</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all the I don't think the BroadcastReciver is the correct way to read a tag. And other mistake that i see is that your intent filter has a category:

```
android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
```

but the correct category should be:

```
android.intent.category.DEFAULT
```

I would suggest that you add the intent filter to the manifest of the activity that you want to start when you touch the tag like this:

```
<activity android:name=".NFC_button">
 <intent-filter >
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
 </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

and move the code that you have in the onReceive method of BroadcastReceiver to onCreate of the NFC_button activity.

If there is no specific reason that you want to use BroadcastReceiver, this will solve your tag reading problem.

Comment: Can you explain why you didn't think a BroadcastReceiver is the correct way to read a tag? Consider my usecase: I'm writing data to tags. I would like the user to prepare the data, then place the tag close to the device for data to be written when the tag is detected. I don't want to start an Activity (to change the UI), because the user is on another activity, getting their data ready to be written.